# How to capture xpath of an amazon product selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

After going to amazon.com I have typed yellow puma shoes. I am trying to capture xpath but not able to do so.

URL: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=yellow+puma+shoes&ref=nb_sb_noss_1
Any product will work.

[image]

These are the 3 I have tried but none of them work.

```
//a[@href='/PUMA-Fracture-Sneaker-Black-Safety-Yellow/dp/B072JPQ3JJ/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=yellow+puma+shoes&amp;qid=1559275052&amp;s=gateway&amp;sr=8-1']

//span[contains(text(),'PUMA Men's Tazon 6 Fracture FM Cross-Trainer Shoe')]

//a//span[contains(text(),'PUMA Men's Tazon 6 Fracture FM Cross-Trainer Shoe')]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Click on it to go to that product detail page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath to get the product name element.

```
(//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small']/h2)[10]//span
```

Replace `10` with the desired product number.